# accessing phpyadmin on raspberrypi running apache2 with vhost enabled

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2, raspberry-pi-os

I'm pretty new to the raspberrypi (Debian) OS but I have managed to ove my websites from online hosts to being hosted on home server, but I am struggling to get phpmyadmin functioning.

I know it works as I have removed access to vhost via sites-enabled/site.conf so that the only site running is the one from /var/www/html

my issues is that when I enable vhost for my sites in /var/www/site1 and /var/www/site2 phpmyadmin no longer connects.

the URL from localhost/phmyadmin thros out a 500 error, however using phpmyadmin.localhost will access the site in /var/www/html essentiall acting a a redirect to localhost

how to I point it to open phpmyadmin

thank you

I have tried the following,

```
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`
```

Then select Apache 2 for the webserver you wish to configure.

If this does not work, then you can do the following to include the phpMyAdmin-shipped Apache configuration into Apache:

```
`sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`
```

Since Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander), Apache no longer loads configuration files from the /etc/apache2/conf.d directory. Instead, they are placed in the /etc/apache2/conf-available directory which is managed with the a2enconf command. Therefore, if you need to manually include the phpMyAdmin-shipped Apache configuration file, you must run the following:

```
`sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`
```

I have also tried adding

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

to 000-default.conf